# how to change all records of a specific field in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, record

I have a table topMovies containing 100,000 records. Table fields are Id, name, movieId and year.
Data in movieId field are stored like (/title/tt0111161/, ...), also in the field "year", data are inside parentheses for example (2008) instead of 2008.

Could someone kindly help me how I can change them to tt0111161 and 2008? (I mean deleting other characters like /title/  for movieId and () for year?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: you should use some scripting language to change them before storing into database

Comment: @tushar: so there is no way to directly upadte them in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE topMovies
SET movieId = REPLACE(REPLACE(movieId,'/title/',''),'/',''),
year = REPLACE(REPLACE(year,'(',''), ')','')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested also your answer and it worked too :)

Answer (score 0):

It worked this way for me:

```
UPDATE topMovies
SET movieId = RIGHT(movieId, LENGTH(movieId) - 7)
```

It subtracted left 7 characters that is /title/, and the rest was what I needed (movieId).
the same way for deleting parenthesis in year column  worked fine, just in order to delete the right parenthesis, I used LEFT(year, LENGHT(year) -1).